# Mono-Tonic Crpytic-Clues

Tags: word, wordplay, cryptic-clues

Answer for this puzzle is one word. All of the following clues have the same enumeration, but I am hiding it from you ;)

> $500 note (?)
>   You ended up turning around (?)
>   Substance emitted through removing online games from personal profile (?)
>   Gas? Initially, no (?)
>   One brown liquid (?)
>   Uniform haiku ending (?)
>   A thousand missing leaders (?)

<sub>This puzzle is a part of [Ooohh, it all makes sense now! :D](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85613/ooohh-it-all-makes-sense-now-d)</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The common enumeration is

> (1)

and the answer is

> DUBNIUM.

Details:

> Roman numeral and musical note; (yo)U and U-turn; bromine and BIO minus .io; first letter of NO and nitrogen; I=iodine; phonetic alphabet and (haik)U; Roman numeral and first letter of MISSING.

Comment: gotcha! its rot13(HC erirefrq, gur raq bs gung vf H, Obeba vafgrnq bs oebzvar)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton rot13(obeba vfa'g n tnf)

Comment: oops... will change that... rip my science @Rubio